# How to set formatProvider property in Serilog from app.config file

Tags: serilog

I know that it's possible to setup Serilog sinks in app.config file ([AppSettings](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings) section) and it's pretty simple with scalar types, but how to be with complex ones (IFormatProvider etc.). Does anybody know how to deal with that and is it possible at all?

I'm trying to simulate this example

```
ILogger logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
    .WriteTo.Sink(new RollingFileSink(
        @"C:\logs",
        new JsonFormatter(renderMessage: true))
    .CreateLogger();
```

but using app.config only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like [JsonRollingFile](https://github.com/nblumhardt/serilog-sinks-json#rolling-file) for this.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:using:Json" value="Serilog.Sinks.Json" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:JsonRollingFile.pathFormat" value="C:\Logs\myapp-{Date}.jsnl" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Nicholas Blumhardt, 
since the `JsonRollingFile` sink has become obsolete as of the 2.1+ versions, how can you set the JsonFormatter property renderMessage to true using the appsettings configuration?
I tried like this but it did not work:

`<add key="serilog:write-to:File.formatter" value="Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:File.formatter.renderMessage" value="true" />`

Overall I have to say, I often struggle to accomplish configuration via appsettings. Some better documentation would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi Michael - there's an example here that should help: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact#getting-started

Comment: Hi @Nicholas Blumhardt,
as far as I can see, this is about the `CompactJsonFormatter`. But I want to use the regular `JsonFormatter` with the `renderMessage` parameter set to true. I cannot find any example for this using the appsettings.config. Am I missing something here? Is it not possible to set this parameter via XML config?

Comment: Ah, sorry @MichaelBarth - no, there isn't a way to set the `renderMessage` parameter via configuration. Subclassing `JsonFormatter` and using your subclass in the configuration is the workaround; moving to `RenderedCompactJsonFormatter` is recommended though. HTH!